# Is it possible to exclude an app from the Screen time activity?

Tags: screen-time

My statistics are skewed because of navigation applications (Maps/Waze), and I wish they were more accurate. Is it possible to exclude an application from Screen Time?
I tried to add Maps in "Always Allowed" but it still counts when I'm on the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Always Allowed* doesn’t exclude an app from Screen Time, all it means is the app isn’t subject to any restrictions.

At the moment there is no way to disable a specific app from Screen Time, you can turn it off if it really annoys you or when Screen Time is displayed deduct the time from the app from the total time if you want to exclude the app manually.

Comment: At this time there is a range of settings accessed by "Always allowed". Like if you've set limit such that apps cannot be used during night time, you could allow some apps (by the app, not by category) to always be allowed.